# How to prevent random output?

Tags: powershell, scripting

When I run my script it adds an output I haven't requested.

```
$input = Read-Host -p "Message?";
$morseFile = Get-Content C:\Users\lukas.downes\Documents\Script\morse.csv
$letter;
$code;
$outputAsString = "";


for ($j = 0; $j -lt $input.Length; $j++)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $morseFile.Length; $i++)
    { 
        $letter = ([string]$morseFile[$i]).Split(',')[0];
        $code = ([string]$morseFile[$i]).Split(',')[1];

        if ($input[$j] -eq $letter) 
        {
            $outputAsString += $code;
            write-host ("" + $letter + ": " + $code)
        }

    }
}

Write-Host $outputAsString
```

and this outputs:

```
> Message?: sos 
> Z
> --.. 
> S: ... 
> O: --- 
> S: ... 
> ...---...
```

which is rather weird, as I don't even use a "Z" in my script.

Comment: Remove the `$letter;` and `$code;` lines - variables in PowerShell do not require declaration, and the garbage output you see are likely the contents of those variables from the last run.

Comment: Is `morse.csv` really a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file? Does it have headers?

Answer (score 0):

If your input csv `morse.csv` looks anything like this:

```
Letter,Code
O,---
P,.--.
Q,--.-
R,.-.
S,...
```

Then this should work for you:

```
# import the csv as array of objects
$codes = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\lukas.downes\Documents\Script\morse.csv'
# for more speed, change this array of objects into a lookup Hashtable
$morse = @{}
foreach ($item in $codes) {
    $morse[$item.Letter] = $item.Code
}

$inputString = Read-Host -p "Message?"
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($inputString)) {
    $inputString.ToUpper().ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {
        '{0}: {1}' -f $_, $morse[$_.ToString()]  # or: $morse["$_"]
    }
}
```

When entering 'sos', the output is:

```
S: ...
O: ---
S: ...
```

P.S. Don't use `$input` as self-defined variable, because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input)